# When one GET request starts working, I want set a variable which can immediately be read by other GET requests

Tags: get, cherrypy

It seems like the module level variable isn't actually "changed" until the request is completed.
I need it to update immediately, so that other requests can be aware that the work is being processed.

Here is an example of the issue:

```python
import cherrypy
import time


@cherrypy.expose
class CherryPySleeps(object):
    status = "not sleeping"

    @cherrypy.tools.accept(media='text/plain')
    def GET(self):
        if CherryPySleeps.status == "not sleeping":
            CherryPySleeps.status = "sleeping"
            time.sleep(10)
            CherryPySleeps.status = "not sleeping"
            return "I finished sleeping"
        else:
            return "I am sleeping, shhh"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    conf = {
        '/': {
            'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
            'tools.sessions.on': True,
            'tools.response_headers.on': True,
            'tools.response_headers.headers': [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')],
        }
    }
    cherrypy.quickstart(CherryPySleeps(), '/', conf)
```

When I open 2 browser tabs, request the page on the first, then wait a second, then request the page on the second, I get a 10 second pause on each tab, then "I finished sleeping".

What I want is for the second tab to very quickly respond, "I am sleeping, shhh"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to guarantee some synchronicity among the requests (threads), you can use a lock for both read and write (or use the lock in the `if` condition). BTW I wasn't able to replicate the exact condition that you described (it worked for me), but at least the lock should *guarantee* that it will be a consistent result.

Take a look at this example:

```python
import time
import threading

import cherrypy


@cherrypy.expose
class CherryPySleeps(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # share the same lock among read and write operations,
        # the read is not "strictly" required, but you can use
        # it to make sure there is no write happening at the
        # same time
        self._status_lock = threading.Lock()
        # the internal status variable
        self._status = "not sleeping"

    @property
    def status(self):
        with self._status_lock:
            return self._status

    @status.setter
    def status(self, new_status):
        with self._status_lock:
            self._status = new_status

    @cherrypy.tools.accept(media='text/plain')
    def GET(self):
        if self.status == "not sleeping":
            self.status = "sleeping"
            time.sleep(10)
            self.status = "not sleeping"
            return "I finished sleeping"
        else:
            return "I am sleeping, shhh"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    conf = {
        '/': {
            'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
            'tools.sessions.on': True,
            'tools.response_headers.on': True,
            'tools.response_headers.headers': [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')],
        }
    }
    cherrypy.quickstart(CherryPySleeps(), '/', conf)
```

There are other ways to do it, using the plugin system in CherryPy, but I think that for this example is not necessary.

Comment: It turns out I was testing in my browser, and it was "Waiting for cache", which caused it to wait for one url load to finish before processing the second. Your answer is complete and I find value from it, so I am marking this as answered.